# process multiple file descriptors from 1 command into multiple commands

Tags: unix, file-descriptor

I would like to do:

```
cat a.txt |\
awk '{
  if ($1>0) {
    print $0
    } else {
    print $0 | "cat 1>&3" 
    }
}' 1>(awk '{print $0"positive"}') 3>(awk '{[print $0"zero or negative"}')
```

The idea is that I want to process both outputs separately from the same command.

Is that possible? How?
Is that NOT recommended?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just `awk '$1 > 0 {print $0"positive"}'` , etc. ?

Comment: I don't think that will work and even if it did would be incredibly inefficient. It's also such an unusual construction that it is guaranteed to confuse anyone, including yourself, who reads it. So unless you are trying to deliberately write something meant to confuse the reader what you're trying to do is not recommended.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano, I would like to process positives with `process A` and negatives with `process B`. My example doesn't make much sense...

Comment: If you OS supports `/dev/stderr`, try having your `else` branch execute `print $0 > "/dev/stderr"` and save a `cat` (-;!. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$1 > 0 {print $0"positive"}' <a.txt >p.txt &  # process A
awk '$1 < 0 {print $0"negative"}' <a.txt >n.txt &  # process B
```

2 processes and the file is read twice and it's probably buffered.
Your example would contain the same number of reads but 3 processes.

Comment: This idea is great. However my ideal situation would be to read a.txt __only once__ and then do a downstream process of negatives and positives without hitting the disk.